# seaborn modify y axis (log scale) to show more values

Tags: python, graph, scale, axis, seaborn

I have plotted a boxplot using seaborn, the y axis is uses a log scale (time in miliseconds). I would like to make the y axis more clear by including more values on the axis. How could I achieve that? The code used and the graph generated are below.

```
ax2 = sns.boxplot(x="xVals", y="Time", data=df2, whis=[0, 100])
ax2.set(yscale="log")
```

[image]

Comment: the "ticks" style might include the minor ticks by default

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

More info:

https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html

Comment: Thanks - I ended up using matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True, which="both").

Comment: It would have been good to create a reference to the ticker object so to explain what it does.